# How do I use curl -u in Parse Cloud Code?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

For -d the keyword *data* exists.
For -H the keyword *headers* exists.
Can't figure out what I need for -u.

For more information, I am trying to access the [Lob API](https://lob.com/docs#verify). It needs -u specification in the curl command. I am trying to find the proper substitute in the parse server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curls command is not available in Parse Cloud Code. But if you are using a Parse Server Hosting (like https://www.back4app.com for example) you can just use https://nodejs.org/api/https.html nodejs module, because Parse Server runs using node.js.